# Draw stars Prolog up to N: draws one line too less

Tags: prolog

The predicate draw/2 with argument N and M should draw up to M stars and should increase N until N > 5. Example: draw(3,5) =>

```
***
****
*****
```

My problem is that my code only draw up to four stars, so:

```
***
****
```

Why does that happen when there is a M1 =< N condition in draw/2?

```
line(0,_) :- nl.
line(X, Symbol) :-
  write(Symbol),
  Line is X - 1,
  line(Line, Symbol).

% b)

draw(N, N).

draw(M, N) :-
  line(M, '*'),
  M1 is M + 1,
  M1 =< N,
  draw(M1, N).
```

Comment: Did not test this, just a response as a comment. Change `draw(N, N).` to `draw(M, N) :- M > N, !.` This will probably allow `M1 =< N,` to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the first clause of draw/2, `draw(N, N).` succeeds before you even get to the condition in the second clause.

But it would be much easier to do this whole exercise using between/3 since it counts the prolog way (both lower and upper limit included). Here are some examples:

```
?- between(3, 5, X).
X = 3 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 5.

?- forall(between(3, 5, X), format("~d~n", [X])).
3
4
5
true.

?- forall(between(3, 5, X), ( forall(between(1, X, _), write(*) ), nl )).
***
****
*****
true.
```

If you don't like one-liners you can define:

```
draw(N, M) :-
    forall(between(N, M, X),
        line(X)).

line(X) :-
    forall(between(1, X, _),
        write(*)),
    nl.
```

You should **most definitely** avoid counting on your own. Because there are two hard things in programming and the third one is off-by-one errors.

With SWI-Prolog you can also use a format hack to print the necessary number of stars directly:

```
?- forall(between(3, 7, X), format("~`*t~*|~n", [X])).
***
****
*****
******
*******
true.
```

It is somehow documented why this works.

Note: the forall/2 predicate is defined as `\+ ( Cond, \+ Action )`. So you could rewrite the last without forall, directly as:

```
?- \+ ( between(3, 5, X), \+ format("~`*t~*|~n", [X]) ).
***
****
*****
true.
```

This itself could be re-written as a "failure loop", but this has some downsides.

```
?- (   between(3, 5, X),         % generate solutions for X = 3 ; 4 ; 5
       format("~`*t~*|~n", [X]), % side effect
       fail                      % fail to backtrack to the next solution
    ;  true                      % when there are no more solutions, succeed
    ).
***
****
*****
true.
```

For example, a failure of the side-effect in a fail driven loop causes it to fail (see the forall/2 docs). Compare:

```
?- ( between(3, 5, X), fail, fail ; true ).
true.

?- forall(between(3, 5, X), fail).
false.

?- \+ ( between(3, 5, X), \+ fail ).
false.
```

Comment: I think I'm not allowed to use 'forall', is there any other way?

Comment: @Julius see the forall docs and also my edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count up, you might want to take a look at the definition of a library predicate that has similar functionality: [numlist/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#numlist/3).

If you take only the logic in `numlist_/3`, drop the last argument and instead directly use the value to print a line, you get:

```
draw(U, U) :-
    !,
    line(U).
draw(L, U) :-
    line(L),
    L2 is L+1,
    draw(L2, U).
```

You will need to add the argument checking however. You could do it like this:

```
line(0) :-
    !,
    nl.
line(X) :-
    succ(X0, X),
    write(*),
    line(X0).

draw(L, U) :-
    L =:= U,
    !,
    line(U).
draw(L, U) :-
    L < U,
    line(L),
    L2 is L+1,
    draw(L2, U).
```